# Azure: How to reliable download a file from blobstorage?

Tags: azure, blob, azure-storage

We create a lot of csv files and store them in an azure blob container. When all files have been created, they shall be downloaded to a certain location within a vpn. This works fine most of the time, but it can happen that some files are much smaller than expected.

The files have an average size of ~40 mb, sometimes the files are between 7 and 30 mb. This is the code so far:

```
private void DownloadBlobToFile(ICloudBlob blob, string fileName)
{
    _log.Debug("DownloadBlobToFile");
    Contract.Requires<ArgumentNullException>(blob == null, "blob must not be null.");
    Contract.Requires<ArgumentNullException>(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(fileName), "fileName must not be null or empty.");

    using (var fileStream = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Read))
    {
        blob.DownloadToStream(fileStream, null, GetBlobRequestOptions());
        _log.Info(string.Format("File {0} successfully downloaded.", fileStream.Name));
    }
}

private BlobRequestOptions GetBlobRequestOptions()
{
    if (_blobRequestOptions != null)
    {
        return _blobRequestOptions;
    }
    _blobRequestOptions = new BlobRequestOptions
    {
        ServerTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60),
        MaximumExecutionTime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(180),
        RetryPolicy = new ExponentialRetry(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3), 5)
    };
    return _blobRequestOptions;
}
```

When the files are downloaded incompletely, there is no error message at all. 
What is the best procedure to check if files have been successfully and completely downloaded?

Comment: Azure Storage Client Library has a couple of ways to check if a blob download was successful or not. For example, it would throw an exception if the number of bytes downloaded does not match Content-Length header. So, did you check if the blob is actually complete on the server side, meaning that the upload was actually successful or not?

Comment: Sure I checked the size. There has been no exception at all, but the files had differences up to 30mb. It looks like this is a network latency problem. Maybe the download worked but it couldn't create the file on destination location? What would be the other possible methods to check if download has been completed?

Comment: If file creation fails, FileStream would throw an exception. If the number of bytes downloaded is not correct, DownloadToStream would throw an exception. Did you try running Fiddler and looking at what the server returns for Content-Length?

Comment: It is not regularly the case that it fails. The processes run every hour and it fails once in three days or so. So it is hard to reproduce. Thanks anyway will give it a try.

Comment: Setting MaximumExecutionTime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(180) can be too short to complete download. After that execution time download will be terminated! So, set this to TimeSpan.FromMinutes(60), it should be enough.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you have control over the name of the file, but if you do you can name the file with the MD5 hash of the file content. Then you can compute that MD5 hash when the file downloads to make sure it matches the file name. This way you would know if you have all of the content. You could also store this metadata somewhere else and associate it, but the key is using a MD5 hash to validate you have everything you expect to have.

Comment: The problem is, that the blog container may be finished with downloading but the file has not been written completely to the file location within the vpn network. md5 is a valueable idea, I will give it a try. The problem from my point of view is the point in time when to accomplish the check.